# How to prevent Freemarker from outputting a file

Tags: output, freemarker

I am working on a project to process data and, depending upon the contents of the data, format it for use by another system.  Some of the data provided are not of use to that other system and some of it is so sparsely populated that it would be of no use - is there a way, using Freemarker, to prevent the output of a file at all based upon the contents of the data?  I have tried using `<#if>` statements, but if the checks do not pass, I simply get a blank file output.

Comment: could you provide some code examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not up to FreeMarker, but to the software that calls it. FreeMarker doesn't create files, it just writes the output to a `Writer`. That `Writer` is provided by the software that calls FreeMarker. So that could implements a logic where the file isn't created until something non-whitespace is written, or could expose a directive to FreeMarker that drops the output file.